# MapQuest account configuration in CKAN

Tags: ckan, mapquest

The direct tile access to MapQuest legacy maps was discontinued. Now we require a sign up for a plan on the Developer Network.

How can I configure the MapQuest account in other to use it in the ckan platform?

Now I have a message in all my ckan sites instead of the map image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For widgets provided by [ckanext-spatial](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial) (spatial search and dataset extent) or [ckanext-geoview](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-geoview) you can use these [configuration options](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/ckanext-spatial/en/latest/map-widgets.html).

For the Recline viewer these options will be available in the next release, in the meantime you can patch your recline.js file as in here: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3174

Answer (score 1):

Direct tile access is no longer supported so you can move to one of the supported mapping tools described in the blog post [here](http://devblog.mapquest.com/2016/06/15/modernization-of-mapquest-results-in-changes-to-open-tile-access/). Those tools include Android and iOS sdks, the Leaflet plugin, and a static map api.

Comment: My question is how can I configure those tools in order to substitute the old MapQuest direct access in CKAN platform? Is there a configuration parameters that can allow me do that or I have to change the base code of CKAN?

Comment: In reply to the original question how to configure the MapQuest account, unfortunately, there is no MapQuest configuration to enable mapping tools using direct tile access. For configuring ckan, see amercader's response.